# Getting the checked checkbox on ngrepeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in angularjs to display several checkboxes.

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="subject in priceinformation.subjects">
   <label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="priceinformation.subscriptioninfo.subject.name"> {{subject.name}}
   </label>
</div>
```

The problem is all the checkboxes are using the same model, hence if I check one, all are checked. I want to do it in a way that the model can resolve to different values. e.g.

`ng-model="priceinformation.subscriptioninfo.subject.{{subject.name}}"`

**{{subject.name}}** should resolve to something like English, History etc, hence a different model for each checkbox.
But  `ng-model="priceinformation.subscriptioninfo.subject.{{subject.name}}"` is giving an error.

Note: {{subject.name}} is resolving correctly used elsewhere, and 'priceinformation.subscriptioninfo.subject' is working correctly.

Comment: Please format your question and/or include a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` instead of `.`

```
ng-model="priceinformation.subscriptioninfo[subject.name]"
```

[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yFFNyo4Y7d1ODRjW4mtC?p=preview)

**Script**

```
$scope.priceinformation ={};

  $scope.priceinformation.subjects = [{"name":"English"},{"name":"History"},{"name":"Maths"}];

  $scope.priceinformation.subscriptioninfo ={};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in checks">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">{{item.name}}
</div>
```

[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZU7Nsraa7kJUnMSovw3?p=preview)